# Play just the good parts of a dvd

Tags: dvd

Is there any solution, hardware or software, that would allow me to just watch the good parts of a movie? For example, something that would allow me to watch Office Space in ~30 minutes, as opposed to its 89 minute run time? It would just skip from one memorable scene to the next. I vaguely remember reading about something similar to this on Slashdot ~5 years ago, but haven't heard anything since.

Comment: Do you happen to remember the date of the article? Maybe on April 1st?

Comment: Here is the /. article I was thinking of (no it wasn't April 1st): http://slashdot.org/story/06/07/11/169230/-Naughty-Bits-Decision-Not-So-Nice and here is the product: http://www.clearplay.com It is a custom dvd player that allows you to play a "family friendly" version of a movie. Not really what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

While technically feasible, how would you define a "good part"? The player software would need some kind of cue sheet that would tell it what portions of the movie to skip to. Any form of doing this automatically would not work well, unless you only had it keep sections with lots of motion or noise, but even then it will likely miss important sections of the movie that would cause the plot to make no sense.

I do not know of any program that does this or of any online communities that generate the cue sheets for use with the program.